# Extract values from a Comma separated field and populate in target using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Looking for an XSLT 1.0 code which will transform the input xml(where item is repeated segment) like below to the expected output

```
<root type="array">
  <item type="object">
    <metadata type="object">
      <GTIN type="string">abcd,efwe,sdsf</GTIN>
    </metadata>
  </item>
  <item type="object">
    <metadata type="object">
      <GTIN type="string">xxx,yyy,zzz</GTIN>
    </metadata>
  </item>
</root>
```

Output expected XML :

```
<Assets>
 <Asset ID="X.test" UserTypeID="XAsset">
  <Values>
   <MultiValue AttributeID="GTINList"/>
     <value>abcd</value>
     <value>efwe</value>
    <value>sdsf</value>
  </Values>
 </Asset>
 <Asset ID="X.test" UserTypeID="XAsset">
  <Values>
   <MultiValue AttributeID="GTINList"/>
     <value>xxx</value>
     <value>yyy</value>
    <value>zzz</value>
  </Values>
 </Asset>
</Assets>
```

With the following XSLT, but not getting expected output, after using the nested recursive template as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet uses a recursive template:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="GTIN">
    <Values>
      <MultiValue AttributeID="GTINList"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat(.,',')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </Values>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="metadata">
    <Asset ID="X.test" UserTypeID="XAsset">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Asset>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <Assets>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Assets>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:if test="$string">
      <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,',')"/>
      </value>
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,',')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An extra comma is appended at the end to ensure that the last GTIN is also found by `substring-before`.

Comment: Now getting an error that "named template split is not available" : 

                        <xsl:for-each select="metadata">
   <xsl:template match="GTIN">
       <xsl:attribute name="AttributeID" namespace="">GTINList</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:call-template name="split">
             <xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat(.,',')"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:template>

Comment: `<xsl:template>` must be top-level, not nested inside an `<xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: Thanks I had tried using it in a separate template outside "/", Could you please help, I have updated the expected output as well now.

Comment: Oops, a typo in my answer: `match="array"` must be `match="root"`.

Comment: This works perfectly, but I already have an existing loop for other elements from input xml and looping over GTIN there, how to call the recursive template and pass the value there ?
<MultiValue><xsl:attribute name="AttributeID" namespace="">GTINList</xsl:attribute><xsl:for-each select="metadata"><xsl:for-each select="GTIN"><xsl:variable name="var11_cur" select="."/><Value>????</Value></xsl:for-each></xsl:for-each></MultiValue>

Comment: The fragment `<xsl:call-template name="split">...</xsl:call-template>` from my answer produces the desired `<value>` elements. Just call it at the right place.

Comment: Yes tried the same :-) but Could you please let me know, how the value from the variable <xsl:variable name="var11_cur" select="."/> will be passed to the template "split" ?

Comment: used <xsl:call-template name="split"><xsl:with-param name="string" select="$var11_cur"/></xsl:call-template> but the last value is truncated !

Comment: `concat($var11_cur,',')` to append the extra comma.